# Display different colors in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, color

I wonder if there is a way in a table of contents to display only  chapters with **different colors**, such as in the sample below:

[image]

Comment: Which document class do you use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The `book` class. I haven't tried anything yet, I am still trying to figure out if that is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a patch for `\@chapter` to provide this automatically, with some colour switching according to the chapter number, having a 'table' of colours defined in `\currentchaptitlecolor`. The sequence of colours is of course completely arbitrary and can be changed at will.

The patch does work for `\mainmatter` - chapter content only (yet).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names,named]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
 {\color{\currentchaptitlecolor}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{}{}


\newcommand{\currentchaptitlecolor}{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}
  \or
  red% First chapter
  \or
  blue% Second chapter
  \or
  green% Third chapter
  \or
  yellow% etc.
  \or
  brown%
  \fi
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Some section}


\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use the optional argument of `\chapter` to provide a `\color{<my color>}` directive along with a repeat of the chapter header. E.g., if you would ordinarily write

```
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
```

you'd change it to

```
\chapter[\color{red}This is the first chapter]{This is the first chapter}
```

Note that this change only affects the chapter header material in the table of contents, but not the associated chapter number or the associated page number.  If you need those two numbers to be colored as well, load the `tocloft` package and use the code shown in the example below.

However, unless you want to create an absolutely gawdy impression, do limit yourself to just one extra color. If you start using several colors, your readers will likely just start to laugh...

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{RED}{black} % don't color running headers
\colorlet{BLUE}{black}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\color{red}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter[\color{red}This is the first chapter]{This is the first chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\end{document}
```

---

If one's going to use the `tocloft` package, it's possible to simplify the setup: By modifying the macro `\cftchapfont` to incorporate a `\color`-related  directive, it's no longer necessary to provide an explicit optional argument in the `\chapter` directives, saving some typing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{RED}{black} % don't color running headers
\colorlet{BLUE}{black}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\color{red}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your answer that, if you load the `tocloft` package you *don't* need to also use the optional argument of `\section`.  I think clarification would improve your answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - better now? :-)

Comment: Actually, no.  You can eliminate the `[\color{red}This is the first chapter]` from the MWE, completely.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I'm at a complete loss. Please feel free to edit and improve my posting as you see fit.

Comment: I took a stab.  Please feel free to rollback, if you disapprove.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Just got back from the gym and had some time to study your suggested code. Very nice! My confusion was based on conflating the macros `\cftchappresnum` and `\cftchapfont`. I've modified the original answer so that it uses `\cftchappresnum`. Your suggestion is much better, for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Christian's answer, without using a patching dependency. Also, colour changes are immediately available rather than having to compile twice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{ToCchapter}
\let\old@l@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{ToCchapter}%
  \old@l@chapter{\color{\chaptercolour}#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\chaptercolour}{%
  \ifcase\value{ToCchapter}
  \or red% Chapter 1
  \or blue% Chapter 2
  \or green% Chapter 3
  \or yellow% Chapter 4
  \else brown% other
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Some section}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Some section}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\section{Some section}

\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\section{Some section}

\chapter{Fifth chapter}
\section{Some section}

\chapter{Sixth chapter}
\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```